# recursive query

Tags: database, db2, recursive-query

i would like your help about a recursive query which I want to do.
I created this table in DB2:

```
connect reset;
connect to sample;
DROP TABLE FLIGHTS;

CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS
 (START         VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
  DESTINATION   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
  DISTANCE  BIGINT          NOT NULL    
 );
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Dublin','Bhogrol',5340);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Dublin','Smallville',5500);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Smallville','Seattle',1300);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Smallville','Clacton',6700);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Bhogrol','Moscow',2320);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Moscow','Seattle',3600);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Bhogrol','Smallville',2950);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Rome','Bhogrol',720);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Clacton','Moscow',6700);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Rome','Smallville',3050);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Schippol','Smallville',8990);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Seattle','Schippol',7840);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Bhogrol','Clacton',1300);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Bilbao','Moscow',1270);
insert into FLIGHTS values ('Smallville','Schippol',8990);
```

I want to find all connected flights from Dublin with less than eight
stops. The output from the query should be a set of rows with the following 3-field
format: [ route, distance, stops ] where the route field is a string built up from the
airports visited in each connected path from Dublin. It is a sequence of airport names
separated by the '-' character. But instead of the whole airport name, just show the first
three characters, so that each string looks like
Dub>Sch>Dub>Sma>Sch>Dub>Sma>Cla>Mos, for example.
The type of attribute 'route' should be VARCHAR(40).

I thought to start in this way:

```
WITH path (start, destination, distance, stops)
AS(
  SELECT f.start, f.destination, f.distance, 0
  FROM flights f
  WHERE start = 'Dublin'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.start, f.destination,
  p.distance + f.distance, p.stops+1
  FROM flights f, path p
  WHERE p.destination = f.start AND p.stops < 8 
)
SELECT start, destination, distance, stops 
FROM path;
```

Is it correct?If yes, what can i do then?

Comment: what can i do about the outputs. I must create a new table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH path (route, start, destination, distance, stops)
AS
(
  SELECT substr(f.start,1,3) || ' > '|| substr(f.destination,1,3) as route,
         f.start, 
         f.destination,
         f.distance, 
         0
  FROM flights f
  WHERE start = 'Dublin'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.route || ' > ' || substr(f.destination,1,3) as route,
         f.start,
         f.destination,
         p.distance + f.distance, 
         p.stops + 1
  FROM flights f
    JOIN path p ON p.destination = f.start AND p.stops < 8 
)
SELECT route, distance, stops 
FROM path;
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want exactly. Thank you very much. One more question. Do you know how can I modify the query to select only those routes that pass through Clacton?

Comment: ... from path where 'Clacton' in (start, destination)  [btw.: dep (departure) and arr (arrival) are the more appropriate terms for start and destination]